# Switch back to python 2.7 Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I have installed anaconda with python 3.4 for windows 7 64 bits but want to use a python 2.7 environment.

I did the following in command line

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

and then

```
activate py27
```

now I can read

```
[py27] SOMEPATH\Continuum\Anaconda3>
```

but still typing

```
python --version
```

leads to

```
Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)
```

I was expecting it to be showing python 2.7 version hence my question

Any ideas for where I might get it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your directory to something other than the Anaconda directory (like `cd C:\`). The Windows shell always searches the current directory first, so if you are in the Anaconda directory and you type `python`, it will run the `python.exe` in that directory.